# How to get Admin form's data in custom js file

Tags: magento2, adminform

**Issue**

In my following custom admin form, I want to add a js file and also get data in this custom Js file.

[image]

your help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you create this form using UI components?

Comment: yes, I created it by ui component. Now, how can I add my custom js file to get data from this form?

Comment: Do you want to add the JS file to the header or body?

Comment: I want to call a custom js file so by using it I could manipulate data inside this form